# Get path of process file

Tags: python, linux, shell, operating-system

I'm trying to do a program that needs to catch the full path of files being used (anywhere in the system)
Straight to an example.
I opened a file called "notify.py" whichis in the

```
/home/miguel/Dropbox/prog/python/notify/
```

directory.

When I call

```
ps aux
```

in linux shell, the process line corresponding to this file's process is

```
miguel   11798  0.7  0.4 512320 34176 pts/2    Sl   22:41   0:06 gedit notify.py
```

which doesn't say anything about the path of the file that I actually opened!
What I wanted (and have been looking for hours, be it using ps, lsof or python's psutil) was a way to get the full path of the file corresponding to that process, that is, I'd like, from the process, to get the directory line referenced above.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

You might try to `readlink(2)` the file `/proc/<pid>/exe`, which should be exactly what you want:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 aw aw 0 Apr  7 00:02 /proc/11700/exe -> /bin/zsh
$
```

But note that this is not overly portable.  It should work on Linux and at least FreeBSD, but might fail on other UNICes.  That's also the reason why e.g. `sshd` want's to be called with a full path, so that it would be sufficient to take `$0` (or `argv[0]` or whatever corresponds to the 0th command line argument) to know the exact location of the binary.  There's no portable way to do this.

Comment: What does portable mean?

Comment: And by the way, running that command with my process's ID, I just get: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 miguel miguel 0 Apr  6 22:44 /proc/11798/exe -> /usr/bin/gedit` which does not hold the path of the file, but the path of the app that opened the file

Comment: Looks like you want path of file that process has opened. If it is so, you should clarify it in your question, which is confusing. If you just need process command path resolved (`gedit` here), use `which gedit`.

Comment: If looking for files *opened* by process 1234, look in `/proc/1234/fd/`

Comment: I fall into line of my previous speakers:  Please clarify your question.  If you want to know _all_ files opened by a specific process, have a look at `/proc/$$/fd`.  And portable means (in this context) if something works only on the platform _you_ are using (I guess this would be Python on Linux in your case) or on any other similar system (there's a standard called `POSIX`, defining what a »usual« UNIX system, e.g. FreeBSD, Solaris, HP/UX, AIX, … should support).  `The /proc/$$/*` approach most likely does _not_ work on all of those.

Comment: I used `ls -l /proc/11798/fd` and it gave me a list with lots of lines, but none every referenced a file path. Any alternative?

Comment: That's because this lists you not only every _file_ but every file _descriptor_, thus including sockets, fifos, and everything talked to by an _fd_.  To get every _file_ try to do `stat(3)` and `S_ISREG()` on every entry of this directory.  This would give you only files.